# replace string in php?

Tags: php, mysql

This question is a bit basic and have been covered many times but I'm not sure why my code doesn't do anything. it doesn't update string at all.

this is my code:

```
$fineImage = "users_fav/".$_GET['id']."/$newname";


$icon = "<img src='images/icon.png' height='70' width='70'  />";

$sql = "UPDATE $lchat SET user_message = replace(user_message, '$icon', '$fineImage')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

the problem is that if I change the `'$icon', '$fineImage'` to something like `'david', 'mark'`. it works fine and it will replace the david with mark...!

so why doesn't it work the way i do it?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're probably having some kind of quoting issue here due to your use of string concatenation.

Comment: @tadman, care to explain further please?

Comment: @tadman, i thought that myself.. +1 for pointing taht out..

Comment: Your query should look like `"UPDATE ... SET user_message=REPLACE(user_message, ?, ?)"` where `?` is a placeholder for user data. Those are populated with a call to `bind_param`. This is how you use `mysqli` properly, so if you're still a bit hazy on that, worth reading the documentation more thoroughly. There's some good examples there and a lot of commentary.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff, no body can understand what?!

Comment: @tadman, ah okay.. you meant prepared statemnet! that is how I always code anyway.. this is not my code and I am trying to fix it.. so it will be prepared statements when i'm done with it..

Comment: I'd also be *extremely* careful when using variables like `$lchat` in your queries. Does this table name change? If not, put it in directly. Every variable you have in your query creates an opportunity for problems you do not want to have.

Comment: First step is cleaning it up, and if it still has a problem, then it requires some deeper digging. The way it's written now it's a small miracle it works at all.

Comment: obviously he has `'` in the `$icon` contents so the query will break. just printing the query out would identify this problem so why even bother posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your call to MySQL's `REPLACE(input, before, after)` is failing to find `before` in its `input`, so is returning `input` unmodified.

Why could this be? Several reasons:

1. `user_message` doesn't contain what you think it contains. For example, are the `<` and `>` tags entitized (that is, coded with `&lt;` and the like)?
2. you're replacing a full `<img..>` tag with your $fine_image.  Is `$fineimage` also an `<img ...>` tag?
3. your `before` parameter contains embedded single quote characters. That could conspire to make your SQL string invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$lchat} SET `user_message` = replace(`user_message`, '{$icon}', '{$fineImage}')";
```

Make sure you have $lchat, $icon, $fineImage defined. :)